# How to access a global object inside a method closure

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I currently have a dependency injection module which allows me to create a factory of objects:

```
class DiModule
{
    private $Callbacks;

    public function set(
        $foo,
        $bar
    ) {
        $this->Callbacks[$foo] = $bar;
    }

    public function get(
        $foo
    ) {
        return $this->Callbacks[$foo];
    }
}
```

I then have an event object which stores a method closure and the session that will trigger the event.

```
class Event
{
    private $Sesh;
    private $Method;

    public function set(
        $sesh = array(),
        $method
    ) {
        $this->Sesh = $sesh;
        $this->Method = $method;
    }

    public function get(
    ) {
        return [$this->Sesh,$this->Method];
    }
}
```

I then have a listener object which searches the sessions set and triggers the event associated with that object.

```
class Listener
{
    private $Sesh;
    public function setSesh(
        $foo
    ) {
        $this->Sesh = $foo;
    }

    private $Event;
    public function set(
        $foo,
        Event $event
    ) {
        $this->Event[$foo] = $event;
    }

    public function dispatch(
        $foo
    ) {
        $state = true;

        if(isset($this->Event[$foo]))
        {
            foreach($this->Event[$foo]->get()[0] as $sesh)
            {
                if(!isset($this->Sesh[$sesh]) || empty($this->Sesh[$sesh]))
                {
                    $state = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return ($state) ? [true, $this->Event[$foo]->get()[1]()] : [false, "Event was not triggered."];
    }
}
```

This is an example of this being executed

```
$di = new DiModule();

$di->set('L', new Listener());
$di->set('E', new Event());

$di->get('E')->set(['misc'], function () { global $di; return $di; });

$di->get('L')->setSesh(array('misc' => 'active')); // not actual sessions yet
$di->get('L')->set('example', $di->get('E'));
var_dump($di->get('L')->dispatch('example'));
```

The issue is when I try to access my global `$di` inside a closure, I have googled this numerous times but cannot find a solution.

Comment: Could just be a mistake in your sample code, but to me it looks like your `DiModule` `set` and `get` methods are mixed up. `set` is returning the object and `get` is setting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `use` keyword to access an outside variable from within a closure.

So this:

```
$di->get('E')->set(['misc'], function () { global $di; return $di; });
```

Should be written like this:

```
$di->get('E')->set(['misc'], function () use ($di) { return $di; });
```

Comment: Brilliant, this worked! I will take a look into using this keyword - I've never seen this before ordinarily

Answer (score 2):

The `set()` and `get()` methods of your `DiModule` class seem to have mismatched names / implementations.

The code you posted has these methods:

```
function get($foo, $bar) { /* ... */ }
function set($foo) { /* ... */ }
```

It should most likely be:

```
function get($foo) { /* ... */ }
function set($foo, $bar) { /* ... */ }
```

To make these mistakes less likely, give your arguments meaningful names (like `$key` and `$value`) instead of the generic `$foo` and `$bar`. Then it would be easier to spot.